# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name or any values what i am giving in my code

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, searchbar

I am trying to use textfield as searchbar. I added all the delagate methods. But when i start typing any letter in my textfield its getting crash like :

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.

My object contains ( i.e which i am trying to populate data in my tabke view is )

```
{
"lo_name" = "yourData"
}
```

My code:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        if string.isEmpty
        {
            search = String(search.characters.dropLast())
        }
        else
        {
            search=textField.text!+string
        }

        print(search)
        let predicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF.lo_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)
        let arr=(objectArray as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate)

        if arr.count > 0
        {
            SearchedobjectArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            SearchedobjectArray = arr as! [MyLooVC.Objects]
        }
        else
        {
            SearchedobjectArray=objectArray
        }
        looTable.reloadData()
        return true
    }
```

i tried giving like below :

```
1.let predicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF.loo_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)

2.let predicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)
```

But nothing is getting success. Still getting same crash. Any solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Problem is with `name` property. Perhaps you have connected the outlet of some text field to name which is disconnected from storyboard. Try removing and re-connecting the `name` outlet will resolve your problem.

Comment: No, its also give me crash like `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.`  and `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lo_name.` too?. And i dont have outlet like` name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering your data array is like:

```
[
 {
  "lo_name" = "yourData1"
 },
 {
  "lo_name" = "yourData2"
 }
]
```

You should use swift type array rather than `NSArray`, so your `objectArray` would be like:

```
    let objectArray: [[String: Any]]? 
    let objectArray: [[String: String]]? // if all values are string type
```

And you should filter the array like:

```
    let arr = objectArray?.filter({ ($0["lo_name"] as? String)?.contains(search) ?? false })

    let arr = objectArray?.filter({ $0["lo_name"]?.contains(search) ?? false }) // It all values in dictionary are string type
```

For Struct Array:

```
    struct Objects { 
        var looId : String?
        var looName : String?
    }
    let objectArray = [Objects]()
    // filter it like
    let arr = objectArray.filter({ $0.looName?.contains(search) ?? false })
```

Comment: sorry for late update. My objectArray looks like `var objectArray = [Objects]()`  and lie `struct Objects {
        var looId : String!
        var looName : String
        
    }`

Comment: So you need to filter according to `Object.lo_name` property?

Comment: then do it like `objectArray.filter({ $0.looName?.contains(search) ?? false }) `

Comment: i tried this code`let arr = objectArray.filter({ $0.looName.contains(search) })
        print(arr)
        if arr.count > 0
        {
            SearchedobjectArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            SearchedobjectArray = arr
            
        }
        else
        {
            SearchedobjectArray=objectArray
        }`

Comment: but still, i was not able to search ...if i type other name..still my data is  in my table view...my searched name data is not coming

Comment: please any solution on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522528/not-able-to-search-the-data-in-my-table-view